# Unexpected token } in JSON config for Contentful

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

While following the [tutorial from Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2019/04/05/nuxtjs-contentful-seo-blog/) for setting up a blog I encountered an error I'm unable to get past.

I've tried changing a few things inside the JSON file but am limited in what I can change.

.contentful.json

```
{
  "CTF_SPACE_ID": "uw...oj",
  "CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN": "yIQp...rs",
  "CTF_PERSON_ID": "15...0m",
  "CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID": "blogPost",
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
const config = require('./.contentful.json')

module.exports = {
env: {
    CTF_SPACE_ID: config.CTF_SPACE_ID,
    CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN: config.CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    CTF_PERSON_ID: config.CTF_PERSON_ID,
    CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID: config.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID
  },
```

Expected:  When I run `npm run dev` the website is served
Actual: When I run `npm run dev` the error "Unexpected token } in .contentful.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "CTF_SPACE_ID": "uw...oj",
  "CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN": "yIQp...rs",
  "CTF_PERSON_ID": "15...0m",
  "CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID": "blogPost"
}
```

Remove the trailing comma from the last key value pair, otherwise it's not valid JSON

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks!